# Why background has small dots when I using YoutubePlayerIFrame?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm using [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe) for my web app.

I wrote code below in `FutureBuilder` in `StatefulWidget` .

```
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                    child: YoutubePlayerIFrame(
                      controller: youtubeController,
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    ),
                  ),
```

This code is the cause of this question. Only when this code is wroten will the dots appear in the background. Like this pic;

[image]

When I remove above code, background is fine.

---

`youtubeController`

```
  YoutubePlayerController youtubeController = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: "XgUOSS30OQk",
    params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
      showVideoAnnotations: false,
      autoPlay: false,
      startAt: Duration(seconds: 0),
      showControls: true,
      showFullscreenButton: false,
    ),
  );
```

Widgets are working fine except for background glitches. No errors occurred.
My memory may not be correct, but I feel that this has happened without using a third-party api before.
What is the solution?

**Additional**

I changed `index.html` to show loading circle while init, referring [here](https://itnext.io/fix-flutter-web-loading-time-with-a-loading-spinner-c5dd36a29f5b). Then background is like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can’t still understand why this happen. but I could solve this problem.
The solution is easy; just add some widget in same Column().

```
        child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        Text("AAAAAA"), // Text() solve this issue. idk why
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
          child: YoutubePlayerIFrame(
            controller: YoutubePlayerController(
              initialVideoId: "XgUOSS30OQk",
              params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
                showVideoAnnotations: false,
                autoPlay: false,
                startAt: Duration(seconds: 0),
                showControls: true,
                showFullscreenButton: false,
              ),
            ),
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```